# Append AJAX items to masonry with infinite scroll

Tags: ajax

I've searched around and looked at a bunch of different logic, and think I'm very close but simply can't get my infinite scroll script to append my data to masonry. I have an AJAX file while is pulling the data, and this is the main line inside of the file which pulls the data when scrolling:

```
        function getData() {

            // Post data to ajax.php
            $.post('ajax.php', {

                action        : 'scrollpagination',
                number        : $settings.nop,
                offset        : offset,

            }, function(data) {

                // Change loading bar content (it may have been altered)
                $this.find('#spinner').html($initmessage);

                // If there is no data returned, there are no more posts to be shown. Show error
                if(data == "") { 
                    $this.find('#spinner').hide();  
                }
                else {



                    // Offset increases
                    offset = offset+$settings.nop; 

                    // Append the data to the content div
                    $this.find('.content').append(data);


                    // No longer busy!  
                    busy = false;
                }   

            });

        }
```

I've tried making edits to the line "$this.find('.content').append(data);" as this is simply taking the data and putting it into the content div which is sitting inside of my masonry function in my main index file.

I've tried things such as

$this.find('.content').append(data).masonry ('reload');

But simply can't get it to work properly and have it append the data.

The rest of the code is working, and scrolling is working properly and pulling data, just won't append to masonry.

Any tips, I feel like I'm missing something very minor.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$moreBlocks.imagesLoaded(function(){

    $moreBlocks.animate({ opacity: 1 });

    jQuery('#container').masonry( 'appended', $moreBlocks );

});
```

Looks like this did it. Thanks for your help Drew, appreciate it a ton!

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issues with Masonry (the new version 3). The key is the .filter() for what AJAX/GET/POST returns. [There is a bug with Masonry that you can read here](https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/374), the work around is to use .filter().

```
    // Make jQuery object from HTML string
    var $moreBlocks = jQuery(data).filter('div.block');

    // Append new blocks to container
    jQuery('#container').append( $moreBlocks );

    // Have Masonry position new blocks
    jQuery('#container').masonry( 'appended', $moreBlocks );
```

I made a little demo to help out here:
http://labs.funkhausdesign.com/examples/masonry/appended.html

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for this, I very much appreciate it. The only very small issue that I have is that infinite scrolling is working, etc. but I'm also using the imagesLoaded plugin to help deal with overlapping. The first 30 items loaded via AJAX, masonry shows them overlapped then I scroll it's fine and the function fires and the images don't overlap after the first set. I can't seem to get the first set of items to not overlap and have the imagesLoaded func fire and work with these items. Any thoughts? I tried wrapping  jQuery('#container').append( $moreBlocks ); w imagesLoaded(function(){

Comment: $(function(){
  
  var $container = $('#container');
  
  $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry({
   itemSelector: '.index-set-box',
   columnWidth: 25
    });
  });
  
  $('#content').scrollPagination({
... )};  )};

Comment: I've found that if you set the image size in the img tag like so <img height="215"> then you don't need to use imagesLoaded. Is that possible for you?

Comment: Hmm, issue is in my case perhaps an image could be different height or width.. the only constraint I have is max-width set in the stylesheet so it doesnt go outside of it's respective div.

Comment: $moreBlocks.imagesLoaded(function(){
      $moreBlocks.animate({ opacity: 1 });
      jQuery('#container').masonry( 'appended', $moreBlocks );
      });

Comment: @Justin - what I've done in a similar situation is to calculate the ratio of height/width. Then I set a fixed width for each item and calculate it's height 'on the fly'

Comment: One other small issue I just noticed is that basically when the page loads for one or two seconds, the items are loaded, say 40 items on top of one another and they are just all sitting on top of each other and before masonry loads you can see them sitting in their position that they would if masonry didn't exist. Any thoughts on the best way to hide this for the one or two seconds that it takes for masonry to sort the items?...